# Mongoose not saving data to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

I want to record every calculation made but cal.save() is not registering the data object in mongodb. Currently its just the mongoose module that is blocking me): Any kind soul out there willing to look at my simple code.

```
# Import library files
restify         = require 'restify'
mongoose        = require 'mongoose'

# Create schema for recording calculations
calculationSchema = new mongoose.Schema
    action: String
    firstNumber: Number
    secondNumber: Number
    timeStamp: 
        type: Date
        default: Date.now

Calculation = mongoose.model 'calculation', calculationSchema

# Start and verify mongodb connection
mongoose.connect 'mongodb://localhost/test' 
db = mongoose.connection
db.on 'error', console.error.bind console, 'connection error:'
db.once 'open', ->
    console.log "Successfully connected to MongoDB"


# Create API server to listen to requests
server = restify.createServer()

# Create GET API that capture all params in the urls
server.get '/calculate/:action/:firstNum/:secondNum', (req, res, next) ->
    action = req.params.action
    firstNum = parseFloat req.params.firstNum
    secondNum = parseFloat req.params.secondNum

    # Create Calculation object
    cal = new Calculation
        action: action
        firstNumber: firstNum
        secondNumber: secondNum

    cal.save (err, cal) ->
        # Handle Errors
        if err then console.log 'Erorr in saving calculation'

    res.send 200
```

Also, in order to check if it is saved, I went to terminal and typed mongo followed by db.calculation.find() but nothing came up):

Comment: What's not working about it?

Comment: oh no i left that portion out. It mongodb is not registering the cal.save() method.):

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose pluralizes your lowercased model name to determine the collection to use.  So you need to look in the `calculations` collection.

```
db.calculations.find()
```

Comment: @Junhao Don't, it trips up a lot of people and it's an acknowledged mistake by the author but we're stuck with it.